# Sort three distinct arrays of objects by property

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have three different array of objects that I need to sort over a `Date` field, where the field has a different name in each group.

Below an example of my data:

```
const documents = [
{
    documentId: 'ADB0125A',
    fileName: 'test_2018.pdf',
    date': '2017-12-02T19:08:52+01:00'  // Field to sort by
},
{
    documentId: '123456',
    fileName: 'test2_2018.pdf',
    date': '2017-12-12T22:08:52+01:00'  // Field to sort by
},
{
    documentId: '121212',
    fileName: 'test3_2018.pdf',
    date': '2018-05-22T23:08:52+01:00'  // Field to sort by
}];

const conversations = [
{
    conversationId: '1102',
    lastUpdate: '2015-10-10T18:19:12+01:00'  // Field to sort by
},
{
    conversationId: '5622',
    lastUpdate: '2019-08-16T18:19:12+01:00'  // Field to sort by
},
{
    conversationId: '112',
    lastUpdate: '2015-10-26T18:19:12+01:00'  // Field to sort by
}];

const invoices = [
{
    invoiceId: "20100392077",
    rechnungsDatum: "2019-02-10"  // Field to sort by
},
{
    invoiceId: "5550392077",
    rechnungsDatum: "2018-02-05"  // Field to sort by
},
{
    invoiceId: "3336392077",
    rechnungsDatum: "2018-12-11"  // Field to sort by
}];
```

**GOAL:** return the lastest 4 results (this I can get with a `.reverse()` once I have a final set listed `ASC`), independently from which source they come from. I would expect to get:

```
const result = [
    {
        conversationId: '5622',
        lastUpdate: '2019-08-16T18:19:12+01:00'
    },
    {
        invoiceId: "20100392077",
        rechnungsDatum: "2019-02-10"
    },
    {
        invoiceId: "3336392077",
        rechnungsDatum: "2018-12-11"
    },
    {
        documentId: '121212',
        fileName: 'test3_2018.pdf',
        date': '2018-05-22T23:08:52+01:00'
    }
]
```

Is it possible to use a unique `Array.sort` method for all the three objects or the only way is to compare them in couples and build the result from partial results?

Comment: please add the wanted result. how should it look like?

Comment: Well, how would you detect that? You'd think just going through and checking if the date is invalid - but look at `invoiceId`: `new Date(20100392077) == Sat Aug 22 1970 01:26:32 GMT+1000 (AEST)` (an actual date, not an error / invalid date).

Comment: @NinaScholz: just added the wished result.

Comment: @JackBashford I know which are the target properties for each array (I commented them in code im my question). Therefore invoiceId would not be in focus for the sorting (even though relevant to fetch eventually the relative object).

Comment: If the objects are under your control you could probably make classes with a common ancestor class out of them and add a property like `sortByDate`. If you later have to display these last 4 items in a list it could also help if you have properties (like `displayName`).

Comment: is the time relevant?

Comment: @NinaScholz: yes, we should consider the time as well.

Comment: @noox nice hint. we get the DTO from the backend, but I would have the possibility to "enrich" the model with a further property used only for sorting. This would make the overall sorting easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take an object with the replacemnt keys for the wanted date property and a flat array which keeps the source and a normalized date propery, sort the array and get the top four elements back.

At the end remove unnecessary information and retrieve the original object structure.

```js
const
    documents = [{ documentId: 'ADB0125A', fileName: 'test_2018.pdf', date: '2017-12-02T19:08:52+01:00' }, { documentId: '123456', fileName: 'test2_2018.pdf', date: '2017-12-12T22:08:52+01:00' }, { documentId: '121212', fileName: 'test3_2018.pdf', date: '2018-05-22T23:08:52+01:00' }],
    conversations = [{ conversationId: '1102', lastUpdate: '2015-10-10T18:19:12+01:00' }, { conversationId: '5622', lastUpdate: '2019-08-16T18:19:12+01:00' }, { conversationId: '112', lastUpdate: '2015-10-26T18:19:12+01:00' }],
    invoices = [{ invoiceId: "20100392077", rechnungsDatum: "2019-02-10" }, { invoiceId: "5550392077", rechnungsDatum: "2018-02-05" }, { invoiceId: "3336392077", rechnungsDatum: "2018-12-11" }]
    keys = { documents: 'date', conversations: 'lastUpdate', invoices: 'rechnungsDatum' },
    result = Object
        .entries({ documents, conversations, invoices })
        .reduce((r, [k, v]) => [...r, ...v.map(payload => ({ payload, date: payload[keys[k]] }))], [])
        .sort((a, b) => b.date.localeCompare(a.date))
        .slice(0, 4)
        .map(({ payload }) => payload);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I would have to change the .entries() as it is not supported by IE (probably doable with polyfills)

Comment: @Francesco Wish I had read that an hour before, I guess WeakMap is not supported either.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in following steps:

- First use nested `map()` to add another property with a name `key` whose value will be that value on which the object is needed to be sorted.
- Then use `flat()` to make a 1D array
- Then apply `sort()` and then `sort()` on the basis of value of that key which we added in map.

```js
const documents = [ { documentId: 'ADB0125A', fileName: 'test_2018.pdf', date: '2017-12-02T19:08:52+01:00' }, { documentId: '123456', fileName: 'test2_2018.pdf', date: '2017-12-12T22:08:52+01:00' }, { documentId: '121212', fileName: 'test3_2018.pdf', date: '2018-05-22T23:08:52+01:00' }]; const conversations = [ { conversationId: '1102', lastUpdate: '2015-10-10T18:19:12+01:00' }, { conversationId: '5622', lastUpdate: '2019-08-16T18:19:12+01:00' }, { conversationId: '112', lastUpdate: '2015-10-26T18:19:12+01:00' }]; const invoices = [ { invoiceId: "20100392077", rechnungsDatum: "2019-02-10" }, { invoiceId: "5550392077", rechnungsDatum: "2018-02-05" }, { invoiceId: "3336392077", rechnungsDatum: "2018-12-11" }];


let keys = ['date','lastUpdate','rechnungsDatum'];


const res = [documents,conversations,invoices]
                         .map((x,i) => x.map(a => (
                               {...a,key:a[keys[i]]}))
                        ).flat()
                         .sort((a,b) => a.key.localeCompare(b.key))
                         .slice(-4)
                         .reverse()
                         .map(({key,...rest}) => rest)
                          
console.log(res)
```

Comment: That's the problem - the OP may not know the name of the date property.

Comment: I just commented about this. The names of the properties I want to sort are known to me (please see the comments "Field to sort by" in the question)

Comment: @Francesco I have updated the answer. Check to see if it works.

Comment: @Francesco I am waiting from your response

Comment: @MaheerAli I was in a meeting sorry. I did not test your code yet. However after discussing the suggestion of noox (in comments above), we decided to try using an interface for the 3 DTOs in order to have a unified sorting field. I will though still test your and Nina solution as well!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *WeakMap* to store a reference to the object property the array should be sorted by and simply look up the value using the stored property.

```js
const flatten = (flat, arr) => [...flat, ...arr];
const PropMap = (props, arrs) => {
 let map = new WeakMap();
 for (let i=-1, arr; arr = arrs [++i];)
        for (let j=0, obj; obj = arr [j++];)     
             map.set (obj, props [i])
    return map;
}
PropMap.SortBy = map => (a,b) => {
   let [l, r] = [a,b].map (obj => obj [map.get (obj)])
   return l>r?-1:l<r?1:0
}

const data = [documents, conversations, invoices];
const props = ["date", "lastUpdate", "rechnungsDatum"]
const map = PropMap (props,data);

console.log (
  data.reduce (flatten, []).sort (PropMap.SortBy (map)).slice (0,4)
)
```

```html
<script>
const
    documents = [{ documentId: 'ADB0125A', fileName: 'test_2018.pdf', date: '2017-12-02T19:08:52+01:00' }, { documentId: '123456', fileName: 'test2_2018.pdf', date: '2017-12-12T22:08:52+01:00' }, { documentId: '121212', fileName: 'test3_2018.pdf', date: '2018-05-22T23:08:52+01:00' }],
    conversations = [{ conversationId: '1102', lastUpdate: '2015-10-10T18:19:12+01:00' }, { conversationId: '5622', lastUpdate: '2019-08-16T18:19:12+01:00' }, { conversationId: '112', lastUpdate: '2015-10-26T18:19:12+01:00' }],
    invoices = [{ invoiceId: "20100392077", rechnungsDatum: "2019-02-10" }, { invoiceId: "5550392077", rechnungsDatum: "2018-02-05" }, { invoiceId: "3336392077", rechnungsDatum: "2018-12-11" }]
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach that I think improves readability:

```js
const by = (name) => (data) => data.map(d => [d[name], d])

const topFourNewest = (...types) => types
  .reduce ( (a, b) => a.concat(b) )
  .sort ( (a, b, aa = a[0], bb = b[0]) => aa < bb ? 1 : aa > bb ? -1 : 0 )
  .map ( ([name, value]) => value )
  .slice (0, 4)

const documents = [{documentId:"ADB0125A",fileName:"test_2018.pdf",date:"2017-12-02T19:08:52+01:00"},{documentId:"123456",fileName:"test2_2018.pdf",date:"2017-12-12T22:08:52+01:00"},{documentId:"121212",fileName:"test3_2018.pdf",date:"2018-05-22T23:08:52+01:00"}]
const conversations = [{conversationId:"1102",lastUpdate:"2015-10-10T18:19:12+01:00"},{conversationId:"5622",lastUpdate:"2019-08-16T18:19:12+01:00"},{conversationId:"112",lastUpdate:"2015-10-26T18:19:12+01:00"}]
const invoices=[{invoiceId:"20100392077",rechnungsDatum:"2019-02-10"},{invoiceId:"5550392077",rechnungsDatum:"2018-02-05"},{invoiceId:"3336392077",rechnungsDatum:"2018-12-11"}]

console .log (
  topFourNewest (
    by ('date') (documents),
    by ('lastUpdate') (conversations),
    by ('rechnungsDatum') (invoices)
  )
)
```

Our little helper function `by` wraps each value of an array inside a two-element array, with the key field first and the whole object second.  (An equally good alternative would be to wrap them in `{key, value}` objects.)

There are four steps in the main function: `reduce` combines these lists generated in `by` into a single one.  `sort`, obviously, sorts them.  (It sorts them descending, for this problem, but if I were to make this more generic, I would probably do a natural sort and reverse them in a separate function.  That would only involve swapping `-1` and `1`.)  `map` simply extracts back out the original objects.  And `slice` chooses the top four elements.

---

There are several variants we could imagine that skip the helper function, and none would be hard to write.  They might have APIs like these:

```js
topFourNewest (
  'date', documents,
  'lastUpdate', conversations,
  'rechnungsDatum', invoices
)
```

or

```js
topFourNewest (
  {key: 'date', data: documents},
  {key: 'lastUpdate', data: conversations},
  {key: 'rechnungsDatum', data: invoices}
)
```

or, with a helper function (`const prop = (name) => (obj) => obj[name]`), we could have additional flexibility:

```js
topFourNewest (
  ( prop ('date'), documents ),
  ( prop ('lastUpdate'), conversations ),
  ( prop ('rechnungsDatum'), invoices )
)
```

or even

```js
topFourNewest (
  {date: documents},
  {lastUpdate: conversations},
  {rechnungsDatum: invoices}
)
```

But I like the way this initial version reads.

---

There are several variants I could see being useful.  We could parameterize the number `4`; it makes sense that we might want the top three or the top ten.  And we could separate out the combining and sorting, using a second function to extract the number of values we want to choose.  These would be very easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

You may write something as below,

```js
const result = [
    {
        conversationId: '5622',
        lastUpdate: '2019-08-16T18:19:12+01:00'
    },
    {
        invoiceId: "20100392077",
        rechnungsDatum: "2019-02-10"
    },
    {
        invoiceId: "3336392077",
        rechnungsDatum: "2018-12-11"
    },
    {
        documentId: '121212',
        fileName: 'test3_2018.pdf',
        date: '2018-05-22T23:08:52+01:00'
    }
]

let fields = ["date","rechnungsDatum","lastUpdate"];
         
result.sort( (a,b)=> {
                let dateA, dateB;
                
                fields.forEach( field =>{
                  if(a.hasOwnProperty(field))
                    dateA = new Date(a[field]);
                    
                  if(b.hasOwnProperty(field))
                    dateB = new Date(b[field]);
                });
                
                return dateA - dateB;});
                
console.log(result.reverse());
```

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: @Francesco please check out the answer, please let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `sortBy` filed to each object in all arrays. Then merge the array of objects and sort based on the custom field. Get the top 4 results. Then remove the `sortBy` column:

```js
const documents=[{documentId:'ADB0125A',fileName:'test_2018.pdf',date:'2017-12-02T19:08:52+01:00'},{documentId:'123456',fileName:'test2_2018.pdf',date:'2017-12-12T22:08:52+01:00'},{documentId:'121212',fileName:'test3_2018.pdf',date:'2018-05-22T23:08:52+01:00'}],
    conversations=[{conversationId:'1102',lastUpdate:'2015-10-10T18:19:12+01:00'},{conversationId:'5622',lastUpdate:'2019-08-16T18:19:12+01:00'},{conversationId:'112',lastUpdate:'2015-10-26T18:19:12+01:00'}],
    invoices=[{invoiceId:"20100392077",rechnungsDatum:"2019-02-10"},{invoiceId:"5550392077",rechnungsDatum:"2018-02-05"},{invoiceId:"3336392077",rechnungsDatum:"2018-12-11"}];
    
const addSortBy = (arr, sortBy) => arr.map(a => ({ ...a, sortBy: new Date(a[sortBy]) })),
      takeCount = 4; // number of items needed in the output

// has all objects with an extra key which field to sortby
const merged = [...addSortBy(documents, "date"),
                ...addSortBy(conversations, "lastUpdate"),
                ...addSortBy(invoices, "rechnungsDatum")]

// sort based on the date property in sortBy
const output = merged.sort((a, b) => b.sortBy - a.sortBy)
                      .slice(0, takeCount)
                      .map(({ sortBy, ...rest }) => rest); // remove the sortBy field from objects
                      
console.log(output)
```

Comment: This approach would not cover my case. I need the "newest" 4 elements from the three arrays. Therefore it could be that all 4 elements belong to the same array or any other possible permutation.

Comment: @Francesco So, why does the `invoices` return 2 latest items? Is this fixed always?

Comment: invoices return 2 results as it has 2 among the (4) newest results. It is just a mater of returning the latest "date type" field.

Comment: @adiga I think you misunderstood. He want to convert all three array into 1D array. And then `sort()` object from different arrays to be sorted based on their different keys. And then he want last four elements out of those.

Comment: @MaheerAli there was not mention of 4 in the original question, so I got confused. Updated now